Question about nested countable local basis on a first countable space
There is a theorem in general topology that states that if $X$ is a first countable space and $x\in X$, then there is a local nested basis $\{B_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ at $x$.
The proof goes like this: We consider a countable local base $\{B^\prime_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ that exists because the space is first countable, and for each $n\in \mathbb{N}$ we define
$$
B_n := B_1^\prime \cap B_2^\prime \cap \dots \cap B_n^\prime
$$
Since $B_n$ is the finite intersection of open sets, it is itself an open set that contains $x$. And it is obvious that $B_{n+1} \subseteq B_n$.
I have a question about this proof: What if $B^\prime_2 \cap B^\prime_3 = \emptyset$ ?
Then, the collection $\{B^\prime_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ will consist of only two sets $\{B_1^\prime, B_1^\prime \cap B_2^\prime \}$. I see that both are open sets, but it is not clear to me that $\{B^\prime_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ is a local basis. To be a local basis any neighbourhood of $x$ must contain an element of $\{B^\prime_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$; so every neighbourhood of $x$ must contain $B_1^\prime$ or $B_1^\prime \cap B_2^\prime$. But to me this does not sound right. Do you have any thoughts on why it is still a local basis? I can provide an example to clear things up.

Let $X$ be a first countable space, let $x \in X$ and let $\{B_n'\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ be a countable basis of $x$.
For each $n \in \mathbb{N}$, define $B_n = \bigcap_{i=1}^nB_i'$. Since $B_n$ is a finite intersection of neighborhoods of $x$, then $B_n$ is a neighborhood of $x$.
Let $A$ be a neighborhood of $x$, there exists $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $B_n' \subseteq A$, hence $B_n \subseteq A$ (by the definition of $B_n$, $B_n \subseteq B_n'$).
Therefore, $\{B_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is a countable basis of $x$ which is also nested (by definition, $B_n \supseteq B_{n+1}$, for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$).

Regards your question:
$B_2'\cap B_3'$ can't be empty, because $B_2'$ and $B_3'$ are neighborhoods of $x$, so $x \in B_2'\cap B_3'$.
Suppose that there exists a local base $\mathcal{B}$ with finite cardinality at a point $x$ of $X$. Let $A = \bigcap \mathcal{B}$. As $A$ is a finite intersection of neighborhoods of $x$, then $A$ is a neighborhood of $x$. And, as $\mathcal{B}$ is a local base of $x$, then $\{A\}$ is a local base of $x$.
It shouldn't sound wrong to you. Instead, if the space verifies sufficiently strong separation axioms, you can obtain more information about $A$.
Let $\mathcal{N}_x$ denote the set of neighborhoods of $x$. If the space is $T_1$, then $\{x\} = \bigcap \mathcal{N}_x$. And, as $\{A\}$ is a local base of $x$, then $\{x\} = \bigcap_{U \in \mathcal{N}_x} U \supseteq A$, hence $A = \{x\}$. More generally, if the space is $R_0$, then $\overline{\{x\}} = \bigcap \mathcal{N}_x$. And, analogously, $A = \overline{\{x\}}$.
